# Split string and delete every second space in java

Tags: java, split, format, spaces

I have log data in a raw file. It looks like this:

```
"2 A U W 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 6 0 0 1 0 0 0        U S E R N 1      F T Y 0 0 0 0 0 0 D 9         2 A I L 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 6"
```

and so on.

I need to substring this string on messages of equal length (From "2 A U W" to "4 A I L" 400 bytes). This is made by `String as = s.substring(0,400).toLowerCase()`. But this is not enough for me. I want to make a message like this:

```
2auw 
20011111600100 
usern1 
fty000000d9
```

Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a back slash n "\n" to add line breaks to your string.

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it is one way to do it:
If you know where you need the line breaks you can substring and add the back slash n. Something like this:

```
String s = as.substring(0,4) + "\n" + as.substring(4,18) + "\n" + //....and so on
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! It was be helpful:) I use your constuction to make a string with /n. Then i replace all spaces with nothing. And it works. Thanks to Naveen Babu and you, Marimaf. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will get your work done. If you are having a lot of data like the above line, we will have to figure some other logic. I don't think it will be apt for millions of records.

```
String asd = "2 A U W 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 6 0 0 1 0 0 0        U S E R N 1      F T Y 0 0 0 0 0 0 D 9         2 A I L 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 6";
asd = asd.replaceAll("      ", "\n");
asd= asd.replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println(asd);
```

Please note the space between `"U S E R N 1"` and `"F T Y 0 0 0 0 0 0 D 9"` is having minumum number of simultaneous spaces. So, I have used that number of spaces to insert new line character.
The logic will result in wrong output if space between characters is greater than two times this `<6 space>` string. ie: there will be `<12 spaces>` continuously.
To solve that you can insert this code just before printing. But use it only if such data happens.

```
asd= asd.replaceAll("\n\n", "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks. I use string s.replaceAll(" ",""); and construction by Marimaf

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
String[] split = s.split("\\s+");
```

You may need to tweak the reg-exp.